# an ONLINE COMPILE app using NODE.JS?

Tags: shell, node.js, compiler-construction

assume I want to do a online compile web app based on Node.js that:

- User can upload his code (CPP for example)
- The server compile it , and response the result (succeed or not)
- User give some input for the program (STDIN)
- The server run the program and response the result (STDOUT)

so it means

- interacting with system, or say shell;
- run programs on server, get the result;

which module(s) support these function?

Is there any example for this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such tool does exist.... [CodePad](http://www.codepad.org)

Hope it will help as it did help me while practicing for c like interviews :>

Answer (score 0):

Assume such service existed, one could just write a code that allocate memory inside an infinite loop, or something more malicious.

Because of the reason above (one of many, I'm sure), I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There they are

---

[reply.it](https://repl.it/)
[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/)